# Show that T is a linear transformation (polynomial)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $P_2 $ be the space of polynomials of degree $\le$ 2, $ E=(1,t,t^2)$ and $ B=(1,1+t,t^2+1)$ be two bases for $ P_2$, and $ T:P_2 \to P_2 $ be the transformation $ T(p(t)) = p(t) - 2p'(t)$.

> a) Show that $T$ is a linear transformation.
>
> b) Find the image $T(q(t))$ of the polynomial $q(t)=1+2t+3t^2$

For the first question.

> $T(p(t)+q(t)) = [p(t)+q(t)] + 2[p(t)+q(t)]$
> $= [p(t)+2p(t)]+[q(t)+2q(t)] $
> $= T(p(t))+T(q(t))$
>
> $T(c*p(t))=[c*p(t)]+2[c*p(t)]=c*[p(t)+2p(t)]=c*T(p(t))$

Is this correct?
I am not sure how to find the image $T(q(t))$ of the polynomial $q(t)=1+2t+3t^2$

Answer (score 1):

In your proof, you forgot to do the differentiation portion of $T$.

Here is how it goes:
Is T linear? 
$T(q(t)+p(t))=p(t)+q(t)-2(p(t)+q(t))'=p(t)+q(t)-2p(t)'-2q(t)'=p(t)-2p'(t)+q(t)-2q'(t)=T(q(t))+T(p(t))$, satisfying additivity.

$aT(q(t))=a(q(t)-2q'(t))=aq(t)-2aq'(t)=T(aq(t))$, satisfying multiplicativity.

For part b, how about starting by looking at what $T$ does to the polynomial $q(t)=1+2t+3t^2$?

By the way, you can make this into a matrix problem fairly easily if that is easier. Also, note that in part 1, you should notice that differentiation is actually a linear operator on polynomials (and the space of functions!)